Convert a PDF file to image with best quality
I am converting a PDF to an image using PDFBox. The best resolution I can currently achieve in the output image is 72 pixels per inch (PPI) irrespective of the DPI value in the conversion. However, I need a higher resolution. Can you please provide suggestions on how to achieve a better resolution?
 PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(pdfDocument);
 BufferedImage bufferedImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(FIRST_PAGE, PDF_DPI, ImageType.RGB); // PDF_DPI = 360

ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, PNG_EXTENSION, byteArrayOutputStream);
return byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();



If you pass 300 instead of PDF_DPI, that does what you want.  Right?

If a PDF contains a raster image, then you won't get a better quality than the original image itself. Maybe share your PDF and explain what you don't like.

@TimRoberts No, it does not. even for the PDF_DPI of 300, in the resulting image I am still seeing 72 pixels per inch resolution.

@TilmanHausherr @K J Please find the Pdf and images created out of it in below link. Please let me know your suggestions.
https://filetransfer.io/manage-package/kg9ll7N8

404 Page not found for that link

How do you know you get 72 DPI in the output?  Do you get more pixels?  The DPI in the image header is essentially meaningless.  Too many apps forget to update that.

@TimRoberts I am opening it in my Macbook using preview app. In the preview app, I am able to see the image dpi using Inspector.

@g00se it is working fine for me. Can you please double check.

@TilmanHausherr @K J Please find the Pdf and images created out of it in below link. Please let me know your suggestions. filetransfer.io/manage-package/kg9ll7N8
The pdf has lot of images and they are highly resolute. but in the output image, the dpi is always  72 pixels per inch (PPI) irrespective of the how high the DPI value is in  pdf to image conversion.

Your link gets a 404.  The Mac Inspector has NO IDEA what the resolution is, because a bitmapped image doesn't HAVE a size in inches.  You need to check the number of pixels.  Also, as was pointed out earlier, you cannot change the DPI of an embedded image.  You get whatever was embedded.

Sorry it's ImageIOUtil.writeImage(). Corrected comment: ImageIO.write() like you call it does not set a dpi. PDFBox itself has a call that allows to set a dpi (as part of the ImageIOUtil package), but of course it sets the dpi that you pass. And the link brings "page not found". P.S.: BufferedImage does not contain a dpi.

@TilmanHausherr Can you please try this link -> https://filetransfer.io/data-package/kg9ll7N8#link

@TimRoberts The image size is 1674 × 2262 pixels

This link works. At 360dpi I get 2850 x 4500 for the first page and 2850 x 4500 for the second. I've used the PDFToImage utility which saves the dpi. (See here: https://pdfbox.apache.org/3.0/commandline.html#pdftoimage ) Note that the images of the people in the PDF have very different qualities, so some will look better and better at higher dpi and some won't.

Your images are PNGs containing between 26244 and 1267500 pixels. You won't get good graphics results from resizing with Java

Right.  Many of your face images are 200x200 or less.  That's ALL the renderer has to work with.  If you stretch those to 300dpi, it's just going to duplicate pixels.  The TEXT in your 300dpi image is obviously higher quality than the 72dpi image, and that's all you can expect.
